# Loading React Native: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'View'

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, tap, babel-polyfill

I'm trying to contribute to a testing library. The library should provide a wrapper for [react-test-renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) like [react-native-testing-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/master/src/render.js) does.

In order to see if my code worked I wrote a simple unit test using the code I wrote for the library. Since this was the first test for React Native I added `react-native` as a dev dependency together with `metro-react-native-babel-preset`. Furthermore, I added the preset to babel.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ]
}
```

The library does its assertions using [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape).

Now, every test (`npm test`) throws the error:

```
> node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill source/test
/path/to/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory
```

When I remove the preset from the babel config, I get the error:

```
(node:1841) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'View'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.get View [as View] (/path/to/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:165:12)
    at _callee7$ (/path/to/source/test.js:110:6)
    at tryCatch (/path/to/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/path/to/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/path/to/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at step (/path/to/source/test.js:27:191)
(node:1841) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:1841) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
not ok 10 test exited without ending
  ---
    operator: fail
    at: process.<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/tape/index.js:90:19)
    stack: |-
      Error: test exited without ending
          at Test.assert [as _assert] (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:226:54)
          at Test.bound [as _assert] (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:77:32)
          at Test.fail (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:319:10)
          at Test.bound [as fail] (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:77:32)
          at Test._exit (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:191:14)
          at Test.bound (/path/to/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:77:32)
          at process.<anonymous> (/path/to/node_modules/tape/index.js:90:19)
          at process.emit (events.js:194:15)
```

How can I get React Native components to run in my test in a library (and outside of an `expo init` or `react-native init` project?

**EDIT:** I found out that the repo is using Babel 6, which is why the metro preset doesn't seem to work. So I exchanged it for `babel-preset-react-native` and now I'm back to the initial error that `View` can't be found.

**EDIT 2:** `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint source && echo 'Lint complete.'",
    "typecheck": "npx -p typescript tsc --rootDir . source/test.js --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit --lib es6 --jsx react && echo 'TypeScript check complete.'",
    "ts": "npm run -s typecheck",
    "test": "node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill source/test",
    "watch": "watch 'clear && npm run -s test | tap-nirvana && npm run -s lint && npm run -s typecheck' source",
    "precommit": "npm run -s test && npm run -s lint && npm run -s typecheck"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "10.12.27",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "eslint": "5.14.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5",
    "tap-nirvana": "1.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.3.3333",
    "watch": "1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "esm": "3.2.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "tape": "4.10.1"
  }
```

**EDIT 3:**
Sorry, apparently I didn't include my code, even though it is a helpful for solving this problem. It's pretty basic. I'm just trying to render a `<View />` using `ReactTestRenderer`.

```
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { describe } from 'riteway';

describe('renderReactNativeComponent', async assert => {
  const text = 'Foo';
  const component = TestRenderer.create(
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
  console.log(Text);

  assert({
    given: 'A React Native component',
    should: 'return a working react test renderer instance',
    actual: component.findByType('text'),
    expected: text
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ? and are the babel presets added to `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` ?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I added the `package.json`. It is a `.babelrc`.

Comment: You haven't included the actual code, so this seems basically unanswerable. What is the code that references `View`? What is `View` itself? How are you loading it?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I edited the question. Let me know if this helps, I'm still stuck with this  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native), "*Starting from react-native version 0.38, a Jest setup is included by default when running react-native init."*.

And

*"react-native ships with a Jest preset, so the jest.preset field of your package.json should point to react-native. The preset is a node environment that mimics the environment of a React Native app. Because it doesn't load any DOM or browser APIs, it greatly improves Jest's startup time."*

The point is that Jest is supposed to work with React-Native, and `riteway` isn't. When you run `react-native init` the following dependency is added: `"jest-react-native"`. And a jest preset is added to `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Apparently there isn't any preset for riteway yet.

Comment: I think riteway is not the issue. The issue is getting React Native to run. It is probably more a Babel issue.

Comment: That's why jest works with `react-native`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/jest/setup.js  .   Line 42

Comment: Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717910/cannot-find-module-view-while-testing-react-native-with-jasmine-and-typescript

Answer (score 1):

Remove node modules and install again

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: I would have laughed if it had worked, but no, same error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'View'`. Thank you, thought!

Comment: I also had same problem but somehow it worked for me

Comment: this worked for me :P
node: `v14.15.1`
npm: `6.14.8`
yarn: `1.22.4`
expo: `~39.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything, You need to return a "View"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just use the suggested example in https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html just to make sure nothing wrong with code you have written, then add up your own logic to improve it (Just an idea to debug it). May be add it up in https://snack.expo.io? or github,  I will help you debug.

Comment: Thank you, I did (almost) verbatim test the example using the React-Test-Renderer docs. (I just changed `<Link />` to `<View />`.) Still same error (can't find `<View />`). An Expo Snack wouldn't help, because the code works in a `react-native init` or `expo init` app (and therefore in a Snack, too). The problem is getting React Native to run **outside** of a RN project.